# trouble in converting the text file into csv where one column contains spaces and comma in text file

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python, trying to convert below text file into csv file. Input text file has 2 column one is id and other is name, this second column may contain comma, numbers and space.

**Input File:**

```
1134999 06Crazy Life
6821360 Pang Nakarin
10113088        Terfel, Bartoli- Mozart: Don
10151459        The Flaming Sidebur
6826647 Bodenstandig 3000
10186265        Jota Quest e Ivete Sangalo
6828986 Toto_XX (1977
10236364        U.S Bombs -
1135000 artist formaly know as Mat
```

I thought this could be solved:

1. By putting double quotes separating the two column

   Expected result may be:

   ```
   "1134999","04Crazy Life"
   "6821360","Pang Nakarin"
   "10113088","Terfel,Bartoli-Mozart: Don"
   ```
2. By separating file after first space then applying double quotes in second column.(as ID column does not contain any space/comma)

   Expected result could be:

   ```
   1134999,"04Crazy Life"
   6821360,"Pang Nakarin"
   10113088,"Terfel,Bartoli-Mozart: Don"
   ```

I tried to double quote the two columns by using below code. But it double quoted every word separated by space which I do not want:

```
import csv
import itertools
from StringIO import StringIO

quotedData = StringIO()
with open('demo.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines()
    stripped = [line.replace(","," ").split() for line in lines]
    grouped = itertools.izip(*[stripped]*1)
    with open('try.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, quotedData, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(('artist_id', 'artist_name'))
        for group in grouped:
            writer.writerows(group)
```

Result:

```
"artist_id","artist_name"
"1134999","06Crazy","Life"
"6821360","Pang","Nakarin"
"10113088","Terfel","Bartoli-","Mozart:","Don"
"10151459","The","Flaming","Sidebur"
"6826647","Bodenstandig","3000"
"10186265","Jota","Quest","e","Ivete","Sangalo"
"6828986","Toto_XX","(1977"
"10236364","U.S","Bombs","-"
"1135000","artist","formaly","know","as","Mat"
"10299728","Kassierer","-","Musik","für","beide","Ohren"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the id's appear to be strictly numeric, it seems like using a regular expression would be a good approach. (Note the following assumes you want to strip leading whitespace from the contents of the second column.)

```
import re

with open('demo.txt', mode='r') as inp, open('try.csv', 'w') as outp:
    for line in inp:
        m = re.match(r'(\d+)\s+(.*)', line)
        outp.write('"{}","{}"\n'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))
```

Contents of `try.csv` file after running:

```
"1134999","06Crazy Life"
"6821360","Pang Nakarin"
"10113088","Terfel, Bartoli- Mozart: Don"
"10151459","The Flaming Sidebur"
"6826647","Bodenstandig 3000"
"10186265","Jota Quest e Ivete Sangalo"
"6828986","Toto_XX (1977"
"10236364","U.S Bombs -"
"1135000","artist formaly know as Mat"
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV means 'comma seperated values', so by definition, `','` is used to distinguish between column values. So it makes sense that you cannot (in an easy and straightforward way) insert values containing commas in it.

Alternatively, depending how your output file is going to be opened afterwards, you can use some other separator/delimiter, apart from `','`, such as `'\t'`. (And perhaps save the file as `.tsv`).

In Python, you can use `pandas` to easily create such file:

```
import pandas as pd

outputDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(grouped, columns=['artist_id', 'artist_name'])
outputDataFrame.to_csv('try.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

**Note**: *You don't need to manually remove any `','` from input in that way.*